# How can i download all files,folders from website directory list

Tags: http

In actual this is the website address which hover when i place my mouse icon on a particular file name(A-1234)from the list of files.

[https://abcd.com/distributors/support/engred/Download.asp?From=ENGDWG&Name=A-1234.SLDDRW&File=V:\egd\Adwg\A-1234.pdf](https://abcd.com/distributors/support/engred/Download.asp?From=ENGDWG&Name=A-1234.SLDDRW&File=V:%5Cegd%5CAdwg%5CA-1234.pdf)

But the problem is there are 1000s of files which i want to download.

can anyone help me please on how can i download all files easily without clicking on each file to download it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using a Download Manager, for example, IDM.

Here are the steps you need to follow:

- Click "Options" on the toolbar when IDM is open.
- Pick the "File Types" tab in the "Options" box.
- Add the file type you want to download in the "Automatically start downloading the following file types" section. For instance, add ".pdf" if you wish to download PDF files (without the quotes).
- To save your changes, click "OK."
- Go to the webpage where the files you wish to download are located by using your web browser.
- Choose the documents you wish to download (hold down the Ctrl key and click on each file).
- To download a file using IDM, right-click on one of the selected files and pick the option from the context menu.

IDM will immediately begin downloading each of the chosen files.

Be aware that the website you're downloading from could have restrictions on how many files you can download at once, or it might demand that you log in or undergo authentication before you can access the files. Additionally, make sure you adhere to any licence or copyright limitations on the materials you download.

Comment: According to Hugging Face, the chance that this post was generated by OpenAI is 99.98%